# Which is correct "started to change" or "is starting to change"?

Tags: word-choice

I got a question on my mid-term exam and I got confused. Which answer is correct? The sentence was:

I believe that the weather ....... (start) to change. I felt rain drops on my hand a few minutes ago.

Would it be ***started*** or ***is starting***?

Comment: Why didn't you ask your teacher? Isn't it their job to explain these things? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher is right!

The weather "is starting" to change because I felt rain drops..a few minutes ago.
(The change is continuing as the words are spoken)

context: year 3077, people talking about the 2020s

The weather "started" to change because the environment had reached its limit!
(already happened)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to better formulate Avishek Dutta's answer.
(Choose his answer as solution, not mine)

If you felt rain drops a few minutes ago, that means that it's not yet "raining".
It is starting to rain.
When you feel continuous rain drops, it's raining.

So it is indeed "The weather is starting to change. I felt raindrops on my hand a few minutes ago".

For it to be "started to rain", the sentence should be like this:
"It started to rain. The rain drops are pouring down on me."

Hope this helps elaborate.